# Debian won't boot - Loading initial ramdisk

Tags: linux, boot

I currently have a multiboot enviroment, where i use 2 harddisks one OS on each, 
  Windows 7 64-bit - with windows bootloader on one of them.
  and Debian 7 - with GRUB bootloader on the other one.

I just use to tell the BIOS witch disk to boot from and are using the two bootloaders independently.
But now the debian disk won't boot anymore. It starts grub, and begins to load the kernel but freezes with this output right after GRUB looks like it's closed.

```
    Loading inital ramdisk...




    PANIC: early exception 06 rip 10:ffffffff816c88a1 error 0 cr2 0
```

I've tried searching both messages but it looks like people get this message after kernel upgrades, and do not event get a error message, it just freezes on "Loading initial ramdisk..."

Anyone have any idea on what to do?

I'm not wery good at this, i am trying to find my harware specs, but here's at least something

```
    Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 4 Core CPU 750 @ 2.67GHz(each)
    Computer: ACPI x64-Based PC
    ScreenCard: NVIDIA GeForce GT 230
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have enough reputation to comment and you haven't provided info on what you did before this happened, I'll provide two answers:

Quick search indicates that it may be a hardware issue, so try downloading some rescue CD and try running memtest and other stability tests to see if it's a hardware issue.

If it's not a hardware issue then there's a possibility to chroot into your Debian system to try and generate a new initrd.
You need to boot from some Linux rescue CD and mount / (and then /boot if it's a separate partition), but before that you need to find out which of your disk contains Linux. Everything is done as root.

1. `fdisk -l /dev/sd?` - this will show partition tables for both drives, remember which one contains Linux partitions, their numbers, size and type (I'll assume separate ext4 / is /dev/sda2, ext2 /boot is /dev/sda1 and ext4 /home is /dev/sda3). Based on them try guessing which one of them is / (root), /boot, swap and, probably, /home.
2. Run fsck - because we can: `fsck.ext4 -pv /dev/sda2` and `fsck.ext2 -pv /dev/sda1`.
3. Then make a mount point `mkdir /mnt/debian` and mount the partitions: `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/debian` and `mount -t ext2 /dev/sda1 /mnt/debian/boot`.
4. We will also need `/dev`, `/sys` and `/proc`, let's mount them: `mount -o bind /proc /mnt/debian/proc`, `mount -o bind /dev /mnt/debian/dev` and `mount -o bind /sys /mnt/debian/sys`.
5. Now we can chroot into your system: `chroot /mnt/debian /bin/bash`.
6. Now that we're in your system we're free to rebuild the initramfs, find out which kernel you're booting (`aptitude search '~i' | grep linux-image` and pick one with latest version), then run `dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-VERSION` and look for any errors during the process.
7. After you've regenerated the initrd, try booting into your system - `exit`, then unmount your system (`umount /mnt/debian{/dev,/sys,/proc,/boot,}` - notice the curly braces) and, finally, `reboot`.

If this doesn't help your system will require more analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I get 'loading initial ramdisk' message, too, using system encryption with LUKS+LVM. This happens for me on Debian (netinstall) as well as on Alpine Linux.

Solution: Entering the (correct) LUKS password and hitting enter results in a regular boot.